# How can I merge multiple Cython pyx files into a single linked library?

Tags: python, cython

I have multiple .pyx files, is there a way to import them into a single pyx file and compile that file into a shared library, instead of having to compile 15 independent modules?

Answer (score 6):

At the moment, it seems the only way is to create a master `.pyx` file that uses `include` directives to create a monolithic .C file.

See [project structure for wrapping many c++ classes in cython to a single shared object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11698482/25050).