# How to compile multiple python files into a unique shared library file using cython?

Tags: python, python-2.7, shared-libraries, cython

I want to compile some python libraries I wrote into a single so file using python. The folder structure is like the following:

```
src/
    main.py
    packages/
        lib1.py
        lib2.py
        lib3.py
        lib4.py
        ...
        __init__.py
```

(`__init__.py` is a blank file)

In the setup I got something like:

```
cythonize(["src/packages/*.py"])
compile = "gcc -shared -Os -I /usr/include/python2.7 -L /usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -o packages.so -fPIC src/packages/lib1.c src/packages/lib2.c ... src/packages/__init__.c -lpthread -ldl -lpython2.7"
os.system(compile)
```

By this way, I got the file `packages.so`. But when I import it in python, I got errors trying to use my functions, python says they're not there.

Using:

```
import packages
print dir(packages)
```

Prints:

```
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__test__']
```

Showing that my functions does not exists in the file. But if I add some function in the `__init__.py` it shows it using  `dir`. I tried importing the others modules (`import lib1` and `from lib1 import *`) in the `__init__.py` file too and didn't works. I'm out of ideas :c .

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to put it on one single file or will I have to distribute my program with 10 `so` files with it?

Comment: Your setup looks questionable...have a look at this site which provides detailed instructions and examples to accomplish this business.  http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge multiple Cython pyx files into a single linked library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772966/how-can-i-merge-multiple-cython-pyx-files-into-a-single-linked-library)

Comment: You don't. The import mechanism relies on each module being a separate .so file

Comment: In that case, is there a way to put all of the `.so` into a folder, and in the main import the folder or the files inside the folder?

Comment: If I understand correctly (I'm not sure I do though...), use `__init__.py` to (as with standard Python modules)

Comment: The `__init__.py` in the folder worked. Its kinda strange it works but `__init__.so` doesn't...