# Compiling multiple files to exe

Tags: python-3.x, compilation, python-3.6, cython

I got multiple files to compile to a standalone exe using cython.

#### compile.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("TheMainFile",  ["TheMainFile.py"]),
    Extension("HelperClass",  ["HelperClass.py"]),
    Extension("HelperClass2",  ["HelperClass2.py"]), 
]

setup(
    name = 'Main',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

The `main` file that should be run by the exe is `TheMainFile`

running the following command

```
python .\compiler.py build_ext --inplace
```

creates 3 `.c` files, in the build dir however is no .exe, just `.lib`,`.exp` and `.obj` files.

Manually adding these files to a VS Projects to build, results in the following error

```
"Python.h": No such file or directory
```

Adding the following files to the project from `C:\Python\include` lastly results in `"structmember.h": No such file or directory`

My question is:
How do I compile these files to a binary where `TheMainFile` is executed.

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52959902/make-executable-file-from-multiple-pyx-files-using-cython? Cython is mostly designed to make compiled modules instead of executables (but it is possible), and it isn't really designed to compile multiple source files to one object (but it is possible with a lot of work). You can do what you want but it isn't well supported.

Comment: @DavidW tried that approach with gcc, but then the above errors with no file found appears

Comment: You can work out the path to add to find "Python.h" with the command `python-config --includes`

Comment: @DavidW if you read the question, you'll see I included it ;)

Comment: In the question you say you added some files to your visual studio project, not that you set the include path (which is what Python expects you to do). However I don't really understand visual studio projects well enough to say any more so I'll stop here