# How to Compile Dependent Modules with Cython

Tags: python, cython

There is a simple python source file:

```
import keyboard
 
def main():
keyboard.wait()
```

I tried to compile this file into a C source code file using Cython and then into an executable, but when I run it, I get an error: keyboard module not found.

I would like to know how to compile the keyboard module along with it.

The keyboard module is installed using pip.

If possible, I would like to compile all modules into a single file.

Comment: This is the correct answer for the duplicated: don't do it! https://stackoverflow.com/a/59389683/5769463